# Extracting value from get response

Tags: python, json, python-requests, databricks

I did a get request and received the correct output, but now attempting to extract the path from the out and not sure where to start.

The output looks like this:

```
{'objects': [{'object_type': 'NOTEBOOK',
   'path': '/Notebooks/example/example',
   'language': 'SCALA'},
  {'object_type': 'NOTEBOOK',
   'path': '/Notebooks/example/example',
   'language': 'SCALA'},
  {'object_type': 'DIRECTORY', 'path': '/Notebooks/example/example'}]} '
```

How can I extract the path/is there any good documentation or blogs related to this?

Answer (score 2):

```py
arr = {'objects': [{'object_type': 'NOTEBOOK',
   'path': '/Notebooks/example/example',
   'language': 'SCALA'},
  {'object_type': 'NOTEBOOK',
   'path': '/Notebooks/example/example',
   'language': 'SCALA'},
  {'object_type': 'DIRECTORY', 'path': '/Notebooks/example/example'}]}


for i in arr['objects']:
    print(i['path'])
   #/Notebooks/example/example
   #/Notebooks/example/example
   #/Notebooks/example/example
```

Simple as that :)
To add more, look into how  [python's dictionaries work](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)